# How to abort deleting record when another table's record exists in Cloud Spanner?

Tags: transactions, google-cloud-spanner

I'm using Cloud Spanner with two tables as below.

> **singers**
> singer_id

> **albums**
> album_id
> singer_id

I need to implement two APIs `DeleteSinger` and `CreateAlbum` with Go and Spanner.
Singer cannot be deleted if an album of the target singer exists and album cannot be created if singer of album's singer_id does not exist. Album can also be deleted.

I used to implement this situation in MySQL by getting exclusive lock of Singer by `SELECT FOR UPDATE` but how can I manage this in Spanner?

Is it good to use `ReadWriteTransaction` to get exclusive lock of Singer by reading and updating Singer with no values to be updated when creating albums ?

Comment: Do take both answers below into account. Your description of your MySQL implementation looks like you enforce parent/child constraints in your app to prevent orphaned rows. This should be handled by the RDBMS so you can never have orphaned rows even if users/admins wrote data to the database outside of the app. It's one of the really nice benefits of using an RDBMS. FYI, you can do the same in MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloud Spanner is a strongly consistent database, and will take care of this automatically for you without the need to explicitly lock anything. If you start a read/write transaction, and in that transaction are able to for example select a Singer, then Cloud Spanner guarantees that you can safely reference that Singer during the remainder of your transaction.

Put another way: Instead of `SELECT FOR UPDATE` for the Singer(s), it is enough to just execute `SELECT` for the Singer(s) in your read/write transaction to get the same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Spanner supports foreign keys which allow you to define relationships/constraints between tables. You may consider defining a foreign key constraint to ensure that all rows in albums have a valid singer_id that exists in the singers table. For more information please see https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/foreign-keys/overview